# Cambiar imagen y tamaño de barra de progreso al pulsar sobre un botón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, css3

Lo que deseo es que al dar click en los dos botones las imágenes cambien y la barra de carga aumente (botón derecho) o disminuya (botón izquierdo) según se dé click al botón correspondiente, el botón derecho funciona pero el izquierdo no sé cómo hacerlo.

¿Cómo hacer para que el botón izquierdo disminuya la barra de carga al dar click sobre él? Éste es mi código:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function load() {
  $(".right-button").click(function() {
    var loadBar = $(".load-bar");
    loadBar.removeClass();
    loadBar.addClass('load-bar');
    if (slideIndex == 1) {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar');
    } else {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar' + slideIndex);
    }
  });
}
load()


function load2(){
$(".left-button").click(function(){
  var loadBar = $(".load-bar");
  loadBar.removeClass();
  loadBar.addClass('load-bar');
  if (slideIndex == 1) {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar');
  } else {
    $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar' + slideIndex);
  }
}); 
}
load2()
```

```css
.load-bar-container {
  width: 328px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.load-bar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #341463;
  -webkit-animation: load linear 3s;
  animation: load linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
  animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    width: 1%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

.load-bar2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #341463;
  -webkit-animation: loadB linear 3s;
  animation: loadB linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
  animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes loadB {
  0% {
    width: 30%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

.load-bar3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #341463;
  -webkit-animation: loadC linear 3s;
  animation: loadC linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
  animation-iteration-count: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes loadC {
  0% {
    width: 60%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-slider">
  <div class="box-bg-slider"></div>
  <div class="box-bordered"></div>
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="images-slider">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.playosmo.com/images/games/numbers/tiles/4fd2499.numbers-tile-9.png" alt="">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://carwad.net/sites/default/files/images-numbers-109750-8986472.png" alt="">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.playosmo.com/images/games/numbers/tiles/78dbcf2.numbers-tile-5.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="load-bar-container">
      <div class="load-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-slider">
      <div class="left-button">
        <button class="arrow" style="margin: 1px 7px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button></div>
      <div class="right-button">
        <button class="arrow" style="margin: 1px 8px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola Anderson. no está claro lo que pides ya que lo unico que explicas está en el titulo. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta añadiendo explicacion detallada de lo que tratas hacer. Pegaste un codigo, pero has de indicar si ese codigo está intentado resolver lo que necesitas hacer y de ser asi qué problemas exactos tienes. **Lee detenidamente** [ask] y [mcve]. un saludo

Comment: Por cierto, dices que el boton derecho funciona y que el izquierdo no sabes cómo ... probaste a replicar el funcionamiento del derecho al izq?

Comment: Tienes el código para el botón derecho pero no para el botón izquierdo. ¿Cuál es el problema que te estás encontrando? ¿Qué es lo que has intentado? ¿Con qué dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Hola lois6b, claro que si pues basicamente lo que hice es replicar la funcion y cambiar el boton derecho por el izquierdo y me da el efecto que vez (he editado el codigo con lo que menciono)

Comment: Hola Alvaro Montoro, los dos botones funcionan, pero al dar click en el boton izquierdo la animacion no se disminuye progresivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en cómo estás haciendo las animaciones. Lo estás haciendo cambiando la clase de la barra de progreso y cada clase tiene una animación asociada. Dicha animación va siempre hacia adelante (creciendo) por eso funciona bien cuando pulsas en el botón derecho (subir) pero no funciona como esperas cuando pulsas en el botón izquierdo (bajar).

Una posible solución sería usar valores fijos y transiciones en lugar de animaciones. Al usar valores fijos no estás especificando en qué dirección debe ocurrir la animación y va a funcionar igual para la barra de progreso subiendo o bajando.

De ese modo también vas a conseguir que el código se simplifique y sea más fácil de mantener.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (todos los cambios se hicieron en el CSS):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function load() {
  $(".right-button").click(function() {
    var loadBar = $(".load-bar");
    loadBar.removeClass();
    loadBar.addClass('load-bar');
    if (slideIndex == 1) {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar');
    } else {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar' + slideIndex);
    }
  });
}
load()


function load2(){
$(".left-button").click(function(){
  var loadBar = $(".load-bar");
  loadBar.removeClass();
  loadBar.addClass('load-bar');
  if (slideIndex == 1) {
      $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar');
  } else {
    $(".load-bar").addClass('load-bar' + slideIndex);
  }
}); 
}
load2()
```

```css
.load-bar-container {
  width: 328px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.load-bar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #341463;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.load-bar2 {
  width: 60%;
}

.load-bar3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-slider">
  <div class="box-bg-slider"></div>
  <div class="box-bordered"></div>
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="images-slider">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.playosmo.com/images/games/numbers/tiles/4fd2499.numbers-tile-9.png" alt="">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://carwad.net/sites/default/files/images-numbers-109750-8986472.png" alt="">
      <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.playosmo.com/images/games/numbers/tiles/78dbcf2.numbers-tile-5.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="load-bar-container">
      <div class="load-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-slider">
      <div class="left-button">
        <button class="arrow" style="margin: 1px 7px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button></div>
      <div class="right-button">
        <button class="arrow" style="margin: 1px 8px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Alvaro, tu respuesta es precisamente lo que necesitaba!